# Android JavaPluginConvention type has been deprecated

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When building my android app project, I started to receive this warning:

```
The org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPluginConvention type has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#java_convention_deprecation
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.internal.NaggingJavaPluginConvention.logDeprecation(NaggingJavaPluginConvention.java:185)
```

My app gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'myapp'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myapp"
        minSdk 29
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.2.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

and project gradle:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.2' apply false
}
```

From the document linked in warning I read:

The concept of conventions is outdated and superseded by extensions to provide custom DSLs.

They want to replace some conventions with extensions.

There is an example:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = 18 // Accessing a convention
```

to replace with:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_18
}
```

However I don't have plugins id 'java' in my gradle, I absolutely don't know what should I replace in my gradle to avoid this Warning (error in future gradles).

Answer (score 0):

Randomly I started to remove dependencies one by one, and when I removed picasso dependency, there is no more warning